# Почему письма, отправленные с сайта попадают в папку "Спам"?

Tags: php, email, спам

При регистрации пользователя на сайте, админу отправляется информационное письмо об этом. Вот мой код:

```
if($info=="")
            {
               $time=time();
               $f=fopen("db/drop","a+");
               fwrite(записываем данные в файл);
               fclose($f);
// и отправляем письмо админу
              $message="Текст письма";
              $subject="Тема";
              $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
              $headers.= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
              $label=str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
              $label="admin@".$label;
              $headers.= "From: От_кого<$label>\r\n";
              mail("$_POST[login]", $subject, $message,$headers);
            }
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что все письма попадают в папку "Спам".

Что в моем коде не так, и как это можно исправить?

Или, может ли быть причина, например в том, домен сайта пока что не имеет сертификата (т.е. http://)?

Comment: DKIM, SPF?. . .

Comment: Ну или текст письма распознается почтовым сервером как потенциальный спам.

Comment: Заголовок "ОТ" вычисляется на ходу. Если не совпадает с реальным отправителем, то велика вероятность, что попадет в спам. Функция mail может работать по разному в разных системах. В винде можно настроить отправителя в php.ini, в линуксе скорей всего отправит от www-data, под которым запущен сайт. Опять же, настроен ли у вас почтовик, через который идет отправка? Или отсылает дефолтный сендмейл на локалхост?

Comment: есть сервисы, на которые можно оправить письмо и он подскажет вам, что нужно исправить.  их много, можно найти по запросу вроде "email spam test". не видя заголовков, не зная всех вводных сложно дать совет. это может быть ssl, dkim, spf или даже rDns. Например, на мейл.ру письмо вообще не дойдет, если в заголовках указан ящик на mail.ru, еще где-то кроме как во From. Если не хотите возиться с настройкой своего почтового сервера, то можете использовать smtp сервер почтового сервиса, который вам больше по душе, подключив условную "почту для своего домена".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Или, может ли быть причина, например в том, домен сайта пока что не
> имеет сертификата (т.е. http://)?

Причина скорее всего в том, что домен отправителя не имеет правильных подписей [DKIM и SPF](https://habr.com/ru/articles/322616/) .

Кроме того в `$headers` есть несколько ошибок (и "От_кого" и синтаксис). Лучше вообще удалить `$label` и прямо написать

`$headers = 'From: admin<admin@site.com> . "\r\n";`

Где `site.com` - домен сайта-отправителя.