# Не приходят письма на Email

Tags: php, html, css, email

Всем привет. Есть код:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['Your Name'];
    $email = $_POST['Your Email'];
    $subject = $_POST['Subject'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];

    // Отправка данных на почту
    $to = "vvlsmd2374@mail.ru"; // Замените на ваш email
    $email_subject = "Новое сообщение от: $name";
    $email_body = "Вы получили новое сообщение.\n\n" . "Имя: $name\nEmail: $email\nТема: $subject\n\nСообщение:\n$message";
    $headers = "От: $email";

    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    
    // Оповещение об успешной отправке
    header("Location: contact.html");
} else {
    // Предотвращение прямого доступа к скрипту
    echo "Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте отправить форму еще раз.";
}
?>
```

Не приходят письма на Email не могу разобраться почему. Если кто знает подскажите в чём проблема?

Comment: К сожалению, Stack Overflow - это не про помочь разобраться, а про ответы на вопросы. Ответов на этот вопрос тут уже миллион. Ищите вопросы с подобными проблемами, смотрите, какой из них подходит под вашу ситуацию

Comment: Ну и на будущее. Постарайтесь научиться ставить себя на место тех, к кому вы обращаетесь за помощью. Они не сидят с вами за одним компьютером. Они не видят его экран. Они не знают, какие действия вы совершали. Всё это надо подробно описывать в своем вопросе. Что вы делали, что вы видите.

Comment: Если смотреть по коду, то надо убрать переменную $headers. Не думаю, что это на что-то влияет, но смысла в ней все равно ноль.

Comment: Внимательно изучай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1573102/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc/1573124#1573124

Comment: Спасибо всем, разобрался...